# Dynamically get an item on a django model object

Tags: python, django

What I want to achieve is retrieving an item dynamically something like:

```
x = "choice"
obj = Choices.objects.get(id=1)
obj[x]
```

not:

```
obj.choice
```

The model is:

```
class Choices(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    choice = models.TextField()
    correct = models.NullBooleanField
```

PS

"x" value will come from a request so its value will be dynamic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use:

```
getattr(obj, x)
```